# К каким участкам памяти имеют доступ драйверы нулевого кольца

Tags: kernel

К каким участкам памяти имеют доступ драйверы нулевого кольца (kernel)?
Всем известно, что BIOS можно обновлять, но из 3-го кольца доступа к нему, если не ошибаюсь нет.
Также код который называется "Синий экран", где происходит дамп памяти для выявления ошибки, это файл системы к которому можно получить доступ из 3-го кольца, или заранее подгружен в закрытую память пк нулевого кольца?
Если обобщить, к чему не имеет доступ драйвера нулевого кольца?

Comment: Ко всему он имеет доступ. Нет способа помешать что-то сделать уже работающему кернелмодному коду.

Comment: Код BSoD (Blue Screen of Death) — это часть ядра ОС.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а как насчет режима гипервизора (для x86_64 архитектуры, например)? SMM?